# ArcMap Python Code that Loops Clip (Data Management) Crashes ArcMap

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis, arcpy, arcmap

I wrote a code to clip a raster using a bunch of shapefiles.  It all works up to the clip function, at which point it crashes ArcMap to desktop without an error message.
My code is as follows:

```
import arcpy

# File path to Folder with the Shapefiles
WSin = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# File path to Folder where the clipped rasters will go
WSrast = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# File path to Folder where the raster to be clipped is
InRast = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

# Set workspace to WSin
arcpy.env.workspace = WSin

# Create a list of the shapefiles with full file paths
Polys = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
Polys = [WSin + "\\" + sub for sub in Polys]

# Set workspace to WSrast
arcpy.env.workspace = WSrast

# Allow Overwriting
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Clip Loop
for i in Polys:

    # Strip the shapefile names so they can be used as rasters
    desc = arcpy.Describe(i)
    name = str(desc.name)[:8]
    seper1 = "."
    name = name.split(seper1,1)[0]
    seper2 = "_"
    name = name.split(seper2,1)[0]
    rastname = str(WSrast) + "\\" + str(name) + "_Rast"

    # The problem child
    arcpy.Clip_management(InRast, i, rastname)
```

I unfortunately can't share my exact data, as it's confidential, but I figure you should be able to figure something out here.  I'm assuming this is something simple that I'm just not seeing.  any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Possible problem: ArcMap arcpy.Clip_management expects envelope (which is in fact string) as second parameter rather than shapefile path or physical shape).

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm

So, your arcpy.Clip_management line should look like:

```
 arcpy.Clip_management(InRast, "0 10 20 30", rastname)
```

where 0 is xmin, 10 is ymin, 20 is xmax and 30 is ymax
Now, another question is how you want to obtain envelope values. Do shapefiles contain only one shape inside? Or you want to get area resulting from getting extent of all shapes inside shapefile? That requires some more coding, possibly using geometries:

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/extent.htm
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm

Comment: Each shapefile is only a single shape.  I created them from a bigger shapefile, but I need each shape individually.  Would calling SHAPE@ or SHAPE@XY work for this second input?

Comment: Your solution with desc.Extent in this case is good and simple solution. In theory you might not split the "big" shapefile, add Name Field to every shape to convert it into raster name, and then access shapes individualy with SHAPE@, but that would make your scripting much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Szym.  I figured it out.  I was using the wrong inputs like you said.  I modified my code and it now looks like this (I just changed the for loop part):

```
for i in Polys:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(i)
    ext = desc.extent
    name = str(desc.name)[:8]
    seper1 = "."
    name = name.split(seper1,1)[0]
    seper2 = "_"
    name = name.split(seper2,1)[0]
    rastname = str(WSrast) + "\\" + str(name) + "_Rast"
    arcpy.Clip_management(InRast, str(ext), rastname,i,"#","ClippingGeometry")
```

Works like a charm.  Thanks!